# slideToggle Inner Div When Outer Div is Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a Div within a Div within a span like this:

```
<div id="container">
<a class="tooltips" href="#">XBOX
    <span class="tooltip-container">
        <div class="tooltip-item">Controller</div>
        <div class="tooltip-item">Console
            <div class="filter-item">In Stock</div>
            <div class="filter-item">Pre-Order</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tooltip-item">Kinect</div>
    </span>
</a>

<a class="tooltips" href="#">PS4
    <span class="tooltip-container">
        <div class="tooltip-item">Controller</div>
        <div class="tooltip-item">Console</div>
    </span>
</a>

</div>
```

I added a click function that shows or hides the div. When I click the items within my outer div I would like to expand another filter-item list within the inner div. In other words, when I click "XBOX" it will expand and if I click "Console" that will expand to show more items. How can I achieve this? jsfiddle example listed below.

[jsfiddle.net example](http://jsfiddle.net/Brett24/AQ9zQ/47/)

Comment: use the animate property of jquery

Comment: you shouldn't put a `div` inside a `span`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zNV8T/**

The main changes are in the JS...

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
    //click PS4 or XBOX
    $('.tooltips').click(function(){
        if ($(this).find('.tooltip-container').css('display') == 'none') {
            //first deactivate any active tooltip
            $('.tooltip-container').hide();
            $('.tooltips').removeClass('clickedSortFilter');
            //then activate the clicked tooltip
            $(this).find('.tooltip-container').show();
            $(this).addClass('clickedSortFilter');
        } else {
            //deactivate the clicked tooltip
            $(this).find('.tooltip-container').hide();
            $(this).removeClass('clickedSortFilter');
        }
    });

    //expand tooltip-item if it contains filter-item
    $('.tooltip-item').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        if ($(this).children().length > 0) {
            if ($(this).find('.filter-item').css('display') == 'none') {
                //first deactivate any active tooltip-item
                $('.tooltip-item').css('z-index','0');
                $('.filter-item').hide();
                //then activate the clicked tooltip-item
                $(this).css('z-index','1');
                $(this).find('.filter-item').show();
            } else {
                //deactivate the clicked tooltip-item
                $(this).find('.filter-item').hide();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

...although I did make a few changes in the CSS as well, adding `position:relative` and `display:none` in one or two places, and I removed `z-index` somewhere.

I think the comments in the code explain the general functionality pretty well, if you don't understand some details, just ask me in a comment and I will try to clarify (I fixed adding the `clickedSortFilter` class to the `tooltips` too btw).

---

### UPDATE:

Here is an updated fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/FAZLu/**

- The `spans` are changed to `divs`, and the alignment is fixed (the way I would do it, see the comments for other options).
- I also cleaned up your CSS a whole lot.

Comment: thank you for the help. You mention that I shouldn't put a div inside a span. Should I change the spans to divs? Or should change the spans to divs and also change the inner divs to spans. Would that fix the alignment problems so that "In Stock" and "PreOrder" are lined up under "Console"?

Comment: @BrettKB - It would be better, but I just tried it and it's not as easy as just replacing `span` with `div`. The alignment is not because of that, that's because of a padding-left of 15px in `tooltop-item`. In this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FdUQg/) I added `margin-left:-15px;` to `filter-item` to counter the effect effect (the very last element in the CSS).

Comment: @BrettKB - But to be honest, I would leave that indentation, I think it looks better. I would do it [**like this**](http://jsfiddle.net/X9B6B/), or [**like this**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rg8gG/), making the width of the filter-items a little less.

Comment: @BrettKB - I made a final updated fiddle, see the EDIT in my answer